# Why asterisk is overloaded for types?

Tags: operator-overloading, ocaml, cartesian-product

I still don't understand the motivation.

Why did they made two different operators (`*` and `*.`) for multiplication of integers and floats respectively as if they afraid of overloading, but at the same time they used `*` to denote Cartesian product of types?

```
type a = int * int ;;
```

Why suddenly they became so brave? Why not to write

```
type a = int *.. int ;;
```

or something?

Is there some relation, which makes Cartesian product closer to integer product and more far from float product?

Comment: regarding the first part of your question, see this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8017172/why-is-ocamls-not-polymorphic).

Comment: @didierc you have right to agree with anyone; but this doesn't make you right

Comment: @didierc regardless my debts nobody should damn

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not overloaded, on the right hand-side of `type t =` you are defining another kind of concept, you are defining a type, not a value.

In ML-like languages you can see two distinct language:

1. The language for types that allows you to define types (a specification of the structure of your values).
2. The language for values that allows you to define values (actual values corresponding to a type, functions are also values). That's what gets evaluated.

Since the domain of the two language are really separate there's no theoretical problem/ambiguity in reusing similar syntactic construct in each language and hence has absolutely nothing to do with overloading.

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics, you note cartesian product using the multiplication character. So it is logic to note it the same way in OCaml...

Comment: Why isn't it logic to note float multiplication the same way then?