# syntax-directed definition to determine the type of expression

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, context-free-grammar, semantic-analysis, compiler-construction

Consider the grammar:

```
E→E+T/T
T→num.num/num
```

The grammar generates the expression of + to integer or real. When two integers are added, the resulting type is integer otherwise, it is real.

Give a syntax-directed definition to determine the type of expression. How can I solve this problem? Please can anyone explain me. Thank You!!!

Comment: Sounds like homework. What have you done so far?

Comment: It is not a homework, I was trying to solve this question but can't. Please can you help.

Comment: Syntax-directed definition **for which parser generator tool**? What are required inputs and outputs in this problem?

Comment: Of the top of my head it reminds me of how OCaml does it, see: [Why is OCaml's (+) not polymorphic?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8017172/1243762), e.g. uses both `+` and `+.`